# How to pass enableCBCProtection=false to a jar file, so it can connect to the MS SQL database when encryption is on?

Tags: java, syntax

How to pass *enableCBCProtection*=*false* to a jar file, so it can connect to the MS SQL database when encryption is on?

*java -jar myjar.jar -o*

how can pass the custom argument enableCBCProtection=false in the above line?

we are using jtds jar to connect to the db, which needs this enableCBCprotection flag to be set to false.

Answer (score 3):

From [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=284365810), I think you want

```
java -Djsse.enableCBCProtection=false -jar myjar.jar
```